# Integrate Laravel with AWS cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I configured a AWS Cognito user pool few months ago & connected it to node.js application, everything was perfect

Now, I want to connect laravel to AWS Cognito, I followed the instructions in this [article](https://blackbits.io/blog/laravel-authentication-with-aws-cognito)

I get the following error

```
Error executing "AdminInitiateAuth" on "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"__type":"UnrecognizedClientException","message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}
UnrecognizedClientException (client): The security token included in the request is invalid. - {"__type":"UnrecognizedClientException","message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}
```

I'm every sure the credentials is correct, but I get this error.
Is there any missing configuration in the article?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same 'problem' following the same article. I've fixed it by verifying my credentials in the .env

```
AWS_COGNITO_KEY=
AWS_COGNITO_SECRET=
```

These are the Access Keys of the IAM user

https://github.com/black-bits/laravel-cognito-auth#cognito-user-pool